# De-active-eat the [active] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/active) is at least sometimes used as a meta tag: it's used in the context of [activerecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activerecord) or [active-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/active-directory)

Should it be burninated?

Comment: We all like to eat. :)

Comment: There are entirely too many questions in the web programming space talking about making a menu item "active". Obviously, without that tag, I would spend an inordinate amount of time searching for these questions</sarcasm>.

Comment: @Zizouz212 especially a freshly burninated meal!

Comment: This meta post seems... extra meta.

Comment: It could use a cleanup certainly.

Comment: Active means nothing at all and this tag should be nuked. No one can be an expert in "active". There are nearly 900 questions with this tag atm..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Done.

I re-tagged nearly ~900 questions and added [activerecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activerecord)/[active-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/active-directory) when appropriate.

The tag no longer exists.

#### [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)